# Using a custom <iq> stanza in tsung (for testing ejabberd)?

Tags: ejabberd, tsung

I would like to use a custom `<iq>` stanza with tsung (to test ejabberd).

Suppose my `<iq>` looks like this:

```
<iq type="get">
    <query Xmlns="jabberd:test:sample">
        <search term="l"></search>
     </query>
</iq>
```

How would I add that into a tsung configuration like:

```
<transaction name="online">
    <request>
        <jabber type="chat" ack="no_ack" size="16" destination="online"</jabber>
    </request>
</transaction>
<thinktime value="300"></thinktime>`
```

Comment: Please take a look at these tips for how to improve your question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: please give the some idea for pass custom iq in tsung is there any example please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Section 6.6.3.11. raw XML [here](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/user_manual/conf-sessions.html). You can specify custom XML stanzas using raw type jabber requests.

So your request above would look like this(make sure you escape your XML):

```
<jabber type="raw" ack="no_ack"
 data="&lt;iq type=&quot;get&quot;
         &gt;&lt;query Xmlns=&quot;jabberd:test:sample&quot;&gt;
           &lt;search term=&quot;l&quot;&gt;&lt;/search&gt;
         &lt;/query&gt;
       &lt;/iq&gt;">
</jabber>
```